# Auto import the prop-types package when using PropTypes

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, react-proptypes

Not sure if this is the right community for it but it's worth a shot for me: I'm using PropTypes from the `prop-types` npm package. It's perfect for typing your React app but one thing that's really annoying for me is that my vs code editor doesn't recognise the import when i'm using `PropTypes`. It does make sense to me, since the package is called `prop-types` and you import it as a default import, most of the times named `PropTypes`, but i'm wondering if somebody has a nice trick to make this work with auto import in vs code, or any other way so I don't have to import it manually.

So.. when typing:

```
DiscoverAppsBanner.propTypes = {
  trackingContext: PropTypes
}
```

I would expect that the import would show up here:

[image: image of propTypes]

Anyone out there with a nice idea? :)

Comment: Have you tried with @types ?

Answer (score 2):

From my side, I resolve issue by a crazy trick, I create file with name `propTypes.js` and I import and export library in this file like this:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export default PropTypes;
```

By this trick, auto import is work and refer to myfile, and I forget the anyone import.

[image]

and the import result `import PropTypes from "propTypes";`

Comment: yes, as you can read in the bounty description we've done the same thing :) And that's fine for now, but if we get more libs that are having the same problem than we're nowhere unfortunately.

Comment: Oops, Sorry, I dont see that..., you are correct, the issue here its base on TS Api version for each library is used, so that the fix usually not from vs-code itself (in general), its from the library...I will follow this too...thank you

Answer (score 0):

`prop-types` is missing the type informations, you can add them with `npm i @types/prop-types`